# Is it possible to catch requests from another extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

In my extension I use `chrome.webRequest` to catch requests from any web pages and it works like a charm.
But I can not catch any requests initialized from another extension.
My manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (data) {
  console.log('catched', data);
}, {urls: ['<all_urls>']});
```

Tests:

1. open tab with http://google.com:
   `catched https://www.google.com/`
2. open extension console and run `fetch('http://google.com')`:
   `catched http://google.com/`
3. open another extension console and run `fetch('http://google.com')`:
   `// no output`

Does anybody know if is it possible and if so, how to set it up?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Updated

My previous answer it not correct, see @Rob W's comments.

> But when [@Xan mentioned that extension URLs were visible to other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450304/do-chrome-extensions-have-access-to-chrome-apps/31451082#31451082), it became apparent that this behavior [is undesirable and a security issue, so I removed the ability for extensions to see other extensions' requests](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510802)

### Previous answer

<s>It's not allowed to [handle requests sent from other extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).</s>

> In addition, even certain requests with URLs using one of the above schemes are hidden, e.g., **chrome-extension://other_extension_id where other_extension_id is not the ID of the extension to handle the request**, https://www.google.com/chrome, and others (this list is not complete).

Comment: Does not it mean that requests **targeting** these URLs are hidden, not the requests **sent from** these URLs? Btw with `https://www.google.com/chrome` everything works..

Comment: That documentation note is about the **target** URL, not the requesting URL. But when [@Xan mentioned that extension URLs were visible to other extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450304/do-chrome-extensions-have-access-to-chrome-apps/31451082#31451082), it became apparent that this behavior [is undesirable and a security issue](https://crbug.com/510802), so [I removed the ability for extensions to see other extensions' requests](https://crbug.com/510802#c37).

Comment: @vitalets, sorry, it seems I have misunderstood the documentation. See Rob W's comments

Comment: @Row W, thanks for mentioning that, if convenient, could you please extract that into an answer? And I will remove this answer