# How to detect ajax request which created by other extension content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created chrome extension, which can handle current page ajax request, but my extension can't handle ajax request, which crated by other exstension (that requests I can see in chroome network tool). How can I handle ajax which initiators are other exstension scripts ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to catch requests from another extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926493/is-it-possible-to-catch-requests-from-another-extension)

Comment: @HaibaraAi It's possible that requests made directly from content script (as opposed to originating from extension origin) can be caught. Needs testing.

Comment: You need to show your current code for catching requests.

Answer (score 0):

please take a look at [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest)

> The webRequest API only exposes requests that the extension has
>   permission to see, given its host permissions. Moreover, only the
>   following schemes are accessible: http://, https://, ftp://, file://,
>   or chrome-extension://. In addition, even certain requests with URLs
>   using one of the above schemes are hidden, e.g.,
>   chrome-extension://other_extension_id where other_extension_id is not
>   the ID of the extension to handle the request,
>   https://www.google.com/chrome, and others (this list is not complete).
>   Also synchronous XMLHttpRequests from your extension are hidden from
>   blocking event handlers in order to prevent deadlocks. Note that for
>   some of the supported schemes the set of available events might be
>   limited due to the nature of the corresponding protocol. For example,
>   for the file: scheme, only onBeforeRequest, onResponseStarted,
>   onCompleted, and onErrorOccurred may be dispatched.

According to that, could you please check your [host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) settings and add there `chrome-extension://*` or just `<all_urls>`