# How to intercept other extensions' requests using Chrome extension API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, request

My code is like this, but can't intercept requests from other extensions (e.g. Postman):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details){
    console.log(details.method + " ====== "+ details.url + " ====== " + details.timeStamp);
    console.log("---requestbody----: " + details.requestBody);
  },
  {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: FWIW, you can probably use chrome.debugger API and --silent-debugger-extension-api command line switch to attach to that other extension's background page and intercept pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this code won't.

This is a security feature: `webRequest` cannot intercept any requests from other extensions or Chrome Apps. Otherwise, it would be possible to inject your code if another extension was loading a third-party library.

It [used to be able to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450304/do-chrome-extensions-have-access-to-chrome-apps), but it was [deemed a security bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=510802) and fixed.

**There is no way to override this.**

Generally, extensions are not allowed to interfere with each other (except for external messaging, but both parties have to actively participate) because of privilege escalation concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** intercept other extension requests but what you **can** do is get and then change the extension that you want to intercept and add [**external messaging**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) between those two extensions.

#### Getting the source and modifying it

1. Install the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin).
2. Go to the page in the Chrome Web Store of the extension you want to modify.
3. Click on the yellow CRX button, and choose Download ([screenshot](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/OV3gJcwk5QJk0lkLxta7t_m_hP1VSiJaIgd7w9XmxlVOVBaueTAHurfKSumlsVNXVR9hiEEOtQ=s640-h400-e365)).
4. Extract the zip file.
5. Read the source code, and change what needs to be changed (in your particular case, I had quickly identified that you wanted to change edit `config.js` and change the `"channel"` property). Save the changes.

**Or**
Copy the folder of the extension you wish to modify. ( Named according to the extension ID, to find the ID of the extension, go to chrome://extensions/). Once copied, you have to remove the _metadata folder.

#### Using the modified version of the extension.

6. Visit the Chrome extension page (`chrome://extensions/`).
7. Enable Developer mode, by putting a check on the checkbox in the upper-right corner.
8. Click on the "Load unpacked extension" button.
9. Select the folder of your extension (to know which folder is correct, check whether the folder contains a file called `manifest.json`).
10. Confirm. You're done.

Unless you've made a mistake in either of these steps (including the modification of the source code), the modified extension should work as intended.

**Source: [How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store)**